# USB TV Tuner Not Working

Tags: windows-7, usb, tv, tuner-card

I'm trying to get a USB TV Tuner to work but I'm having troubles. It's a Hauppauge WinTV 950Q and when I connect it to my Windows 7 (x64) laptop it shows that it's detected and the lights on it will also come on. I'm unable to find the CD that came with it so I tried downloading the WinTV software from their website, but when I go to install it, it says I need the CDROM in order for it to be installed??? So instead, I tried download a program called NextPVR. It will show the WinTV 950Q in the devices list, but when I go to scan for channels, nothing is found. I have a coaxial cable connected to it from our cable box. Any ideas on what might be the problem? Could it be that WinTV needs to be installed in order for it to work?

Comment: You can use Windows Media Center.

Answer (score 0):

I was finally able to get it to work with Windows Media Center. It seems NextPVR didn't want to detect channel 3 (even after changing the channel settings). I also didn't need the CD to get it to work.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you also to try SmartDVB (smartdvb.net): it works perfectly with my Hauppauge WinTV 930C and it is free, fast and light.